# Push only certain items from array of objects to new array of arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hello so i have array of objects something like this

```
const old = [{id: 1, name: 'Random'}, {id: 2, name: 'Random2'}]
```

also i have array

```
const wantedField = ['id']
```

So looking this result, i need values only for certain key

```
const finally = [[1],[2]]
```

I have tried something like this but not luck. End result should be array of arrays with just certain values.

```
    old.map((obj, value) => {
          const key = Object.keys(obj)[value]
          if(wantedField.includes(const)) {
          const newArray = []
          const key = Object.keys(obj)[value]
          newArray.push(obj[key])
          return [newArray]
       }
   })
```

So this `return [newArray]` is wrong should return multiple values not just one. Please help regards.

Comment: Will `wantedField` only contain one element? And why do you need an nested array of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one-liner, with two nested maps.  One to iterate over the input array, and another to iterate over the wanted field(s):

```js
const old = [{id: 1, name: 'Random'}, {id: 2, name: 'Random2'}];
const wantedField = ['id'];

const result = old.map(o => wantedField.map(k => o[k]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect sir tnx, please vote up if you found this question useful? Tnx again!

Comment: NB: this will insert a value of `undefined` in each array for any field that does not exist in the original objects.